# impresspages - 1) styling blocks 2) change background color as admin 3) plugins request

Tags: impresspages

I am just playing around with ImpressPages and got three questions:

---

1)
Widgets can be styled.
There are options available, where you can adjust everything.

But what about the blocks?
Where can the style of blocks be edited in a graphical way? (without the need of knowing CSS!)

As an example, I just picked a design from oswd: (example!)
http://static.oswd.org/designs/1547/Greenday/

As you can see, there is a grey header and a green area below.

If this would be an impresspages website, all the widgets (images, texts, etc) could be edited.

But what's about the look and feel of the blocks?

Let's assume, the site's administrator (who does not know html, css, etc) wants to change the background-color or wants to set a background-image for the (formerly) green area.

*) What would he/she need to do?  Any "click to edit" option?

*) Where would he/she need to click, to get the config options as GUI like for the widgets?

I'd expect a wheel-icon like for the widgets where the "skin" of the block can be changed.
Can blocks have skins?  Beside skins, I'd need a real config dialogue window where the site admin can chose the color, background image, etc.

This is honestly very important -  I hope there is a solution!

---

2)
What is the easiest way to create a plugin for the administration area where options can be set?

I want to show a javascript based color picker where the overall background color can be chosen.

The HelloWorld Plugin was a good start, and I was able to save a value:
ipSetOption('HelloWorld.backgroundcolor', 'ff0000');
I was also able to print the value in the frontend.

*) But, I was not able to add a form field

I tried it the ImpressPages like way:

$form = new \Ip\Form();

```
    $field = new \Ip\Form\Field\Text(
        array(
            'name' => 'bgcolor',
            'label' => __('bgcolor', 'Ip-admin', false),
        ));
    $form->addField($field);
```

*) And I was not able to find out how to add a color picker.

---

3)
Are there simple widgets planned like the following ones?

*) Comments (per page)
*) Guestbook
*) Polls
*) Print page
*) Recommend page to a friend (mail)

etc...

Would I need to program them all myself, or will they come out in the next time?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

ImpresspPages is very new and agile tool. It lack many plugins you have mentioned. One day they will all come to the world. We have more and more plugins each day. I would say use ImpressPages for project where ImpressPages has everything needed.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the background. I would go for [theme options](http://www.impresspages.org/docs/theme-options). It is not suitable if you want to change background for particular widget. But should work great to change the background for the whole page.